# Filtering a list with itens with same hour and letting just one in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of multiple items in Python, and the list is generated randomly, this is an example:

```
['12:01;Jhon',
 '13:25;Charlie',
 '14:00;Joshua', 
 '12:01;Dean', 
 '15:04;Derek',
 '14:58;George',
 '12:01;Wilson',
 '15:04;Marcus']
```

And i need to generate a new list with, picking the first item with same hour, and letting the items with different hour:

```
['12:01;Jhon',
 '13:25;Charlie',
 '14:00;Joshua',
 '15:04;Derek',
 '14:58;George']
```

**Explainig the new list**: Jhon was the first item with 12:01, so it is in the new list, and removing Dean and Wilson because they have also 12:01. Joshua and George contain in the list because they have different hours from the others. And Derek was the first item with 15:04, removing Marcus from the list because he have 15:04.

Comment: I'm confused...Joshua and George seem have the same hour -- `14`. Or do you mean the same time?

Comment: *"It is possible to solve the problem?"* - Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set()` to filter out the duplicates. For example:

```
lst = [
    "12:01;Jhon",
    "13:25;Charlie",
    "14:00;Joshua",
    "12:01;Dean",
    "15:04;Derek",
    "14:58;George",
    "12:01;Wilson",
    "15:04;Marcus",
]

out, seen = [], set()
for item in lst:
    hour = item.split(";", maxsplit=1)[0]
    if hour not in seen:
        out.append(item)
        seen.add(hour)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['12:01;Jhon', '13:25;Charlie', '14:00;Joshua', '15:04;Derek', '14:58;George']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a short `dict` solution:

```
d = {}
for s in lst:
    d.setdefault(s[:5], s)
result = list(d.values())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7NCsIwEATge54it7ZQpL9QEjwpCAXPHkoPwW5tMDQlmwgiPnsMraB7m@FbmOVpJz2XzWK8V2jpnnZRXrAs523oo5RGecmKmh8mYZSEtahYlvFW4@TEmld@BLHxmmVVSAbuX1w3/ATa3OCHL1Kh/uNnYa4Oo56QISx4vcmoDUUqZxo2MULDDTsEO8AonLIxdqzuU4oJMYChCE9Koo2H3UMoBxgnCSGLkbONN5B4/wE)

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
x= ['12:01;Jhon', '13:25;Charlie', '14:00;Joshua', '12:01;Dean', '15:04;Derek', '14:58;George', '12:01;Wilson', '15:04;Marcus']
y = {}
for elems in x:
    elems = elems.split(';')
    if elems[0] not in y:y[elems[0]] = elems[1] 
x = [elems2+';'+y[elems2] for elems2 in y]
print(x)
```

Also I suggest using a dictionary for this kind of stuff, but for your output example I turned the dict into a list

Answer (score 1):

### My suggestion:

We need to split up the items into lists [hour, name] and make it a dict:

```
items = ['12:01;Jhon', '13:25;Charlie', '14:00;Joshua', '12:01;Dean', '15:04;Derek', '14:58;George', '12:01;Wilson', '15:04;Marcus']

split_items = list(map(lambda x: x.split(';'), items))

# we need to reverse it first because dict overwrites existant keys in order
new_items_dict = dict(reversed(split_items))

# return it back to a list
new_items_list = list(new_items_dict.items())

# new_items_list == [('15:04', 'Derek'), ('12:01', 'Jhon'), ('14:58', 'George'), ('14:00', 'Joshua'), ('13:25', 'Charlie')]

# And if you want to join them back
new_items = list(map(lambda x: ';'.join(x), new_items_list))

# new_items == ['15:04;Derek', '12:01;Jhon', '14:58;George', '14:00;Joshua', '13:25;Charlie']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
new_list= []
checks = []
for i in item:
    a= i.split(';')[0]
    if a not in checks:
        new_list.append(i)
        checks.append(a)
del checks
print(new_list)
```